# Cakephp 2.x Auth not working in Chrome 74.0 version but its working in mozilla 66.0 version

Tags: php, cakephp

Its is critical problem i facing today. My Cakephp Project not able mantain session with chrome, safari, wheres its working in mozilla

```
public function login()
{
    $this->layout = 'login';

    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if ($this->Auth->login())
        {
            $this->authUser = AppModel::$authUser = $this->Auth->user();                    
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Username or password was incorrect.', 'flash_failure');
        }
    }

    if ($this->authUser)
    {
        $menus = Menu::get(Menu::$default, $this->Acl, $this->authUser['group_id']);

        $home_link = Menu::getDefaultLink($menus);

        //debug($_SESSION); debug($_COOKIE); debug($home_link); debug($this->authUser); exit;

        $this->redirect($home_link);
    }
}
```

After Login Post i check **$this->authUser**. its working fine here. But it redirect to **$home_link**. It takes me back to login. Then i check session i did not found **auth.user** key in session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I had the same problem**
Please remove the debug kit plugin then delete all the cookies and cache from the chrome and its working.